# Running jsp files with Apache tomcat on windows

Tags: java, windows, jsp, tomcat

I installed Apache Tomcat on my Windows machine, and it seems like its installed successfuly. I can see the property window, and I can start the server but I don't know what to do next.

Where do I save jsp files at.. do I create a directory or does apache tomcat create its own directories?

that's my only problem.. how do i make and edit files now that its installed

Comment: You can save your JSPs or Servlets in the Tomcat\WebApps folder. You better take some tutorial on JSP/Servlet programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder structure:

```
 Apache-home/webapps/project_name/WEB-INF/classes
```

all jsp filse should come under project_name folder. and java classes comes under clasess.
Also need to put a special file named [web.xml](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/java/web_application/web_xml.html) in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to connect to http://localhost:8080/ but it isn't working. what can I do?

Comment: Make sure apache tomcat is running on port 8080.

Comment: Check file server.xml under folder apache=home/config. find something like this  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />. it will tell you the pot number on which apache is running.

Comment: Warning: the linked `web.xml` is *heavily* outdated. When running it on a newer servletcontainer you might risk that some (newer) parts of the Servlet API will cease to work. Use the latest version which your servletcontainer supports. Tomcat 7 = web.xml 3.0, Tomcat 6 = web.xml 2.5, Tomcat 5.5 = web.xml 2.4.

Comment: Yes but its just for his understanding and like very basic tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

Create the JSP code that you'd like to write in your favorite text editor.

Select "**File**" and "**Save As**" from the text editor toolbar. A dialog box appears.

Navigate to the "File name" text field and type the desired file name within quotes. Add a JSP extension to the file name -- for example, "filename.jsp" -- and click "**Save**."

Put it at location **C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\webapps\ROOT**.

Go to tour browser and enter url "**http:// localhost:8080//filename.jsp"**

Answer (score 2):

This post will give you description about how you can run your project using Apache Tomcat Server.

I would like to define these terms before proceeding:

Apache Tomcat Server(Jakarta Tomcat): It is an open source web server and servlet container developed by the Apache Software Foundation (ASF). It implements the Java Servlet and the JavaServer Pages (JSP) specifications and provides a pure Java HTTP web server environment for java code to run.

JavaServerPages(JSP): It is a technology that helps in creating dynamically generated web pages.

**Step1**

Install Java.

**Step2**

Install Apache Tomcat

At the time of installation, it will by-default recognize JRE path.

(under installed java location directory)

**Step3**

Now Go-To:

Start

Programs

APACHE TOMCAT

MONITOR TOMCAT

**Step4**

An icon will appear on the taskbar, this icon will automatically appear after following

above step:

**Step5**

Click on that icon and START TOMCAT, you can see the following dialog box:

**Step6**

Now open Mozilla Firefox(or any other browser)

**Step7**

Type
        `[http://localhost:8080/][1]`  on address bar and press enter.

The same can be seen here:

**Step8**

It will show tomcat, as shown in above window.

(if not, then try again, may be a problem in installation or you’re not following above

steps correctly

**Step9**

Now, go to:

C:drive

Programs Files

Apache Software Foundation

tomcat

web-apps

(or navigate where you have installed APACHE TOMCAT)

**Step10**

Open web-apps and “copy your project” or “make new folder”, which you want to run in JSP.

Example: amit2012PROJECT

Now, go back :

Tomcat

Root

Copy Web-inf from root

Paste this “web-inf” in your project folder i.e. amit2012PROJECT

**Step11**

Create a text file and name it as first.jsp, use the code shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>blog post:ApacheTomcatServer</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <%-- START --%>
  <%
   out.println("UserName = amit2012, ");
   out.println("Running first program in JSP.");
 %>
 <%-- END --%>

 </body>
 </html>
```

It includes HTML tags and encloses a JSP scriptlet which is a fragment of Java code           that is run when the user requests the page.
**Step12**

Now for running your folder [ Eg. amit2012PROJECT as shown above]

```
[http://localhost:8080/][2]foldername.extension in any WebBrowser i.e:

[http://localhost:8080/amit2012PROJECT/first.jsp][3]
```

The Project will run successfully

Now, you can successfully try running JSP with ApacheTomcatServer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this first. [The file and directory structure of a web app](http://www.examulator.com/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=455).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start your server by going to bin folder present in tomcat
then double click the start.bat 
now the server is up and running
now open a browser ,open tomcat

u will see the homepage of server 
i think u might have already created a folder in webapps folder of tomcat
directory structure would look like this tomcatfolder --> webapps --> your file name let it be some " test " --> then the jsp file you have created
to run a jsp file located as shown in the above directory structure u need to type the url                                  localhost:8080/test/file name of jsp
if it runs ok or otherwise if
server throws an error then it needs tools.jar file
go to the directory where u have ur jdk kit 
open jdk file, then open lib file
copy tools.jar present in it
now again go to tomcat folder ,
open it and then go to lib folder paste it down there
over,go to browser type the url
              $locallhost:8080/test/file name of jsp( dont type the $ symbol)
it should run now now..........